# Why does the default edit description say "added 500 characters in body"?

Tags: bug, edits

When editing my own posts, the default edit description sometimes says "added 500 characters in body," even if I only add a couple characters.

EDIT: apparently this doesn't happen every time--in fact, it seems rather tricky to reproduce. Here is the original edit history that led me to ask this question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16331800/revisions

Comment: Never saw that, can you post screenshot?

Comment: @Sha I don't have an easily screenshot-able example, but you can look at the edit history, for instance, here: [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16331800/1858225). I'll go generate a new example using the sandbox.

Comment: Can't reproduce, see [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/127080/revisions). It correctly says "added 35 characters in body"

Comment: @Sha looks like this doesn't happen on the sandbox, since answers there are automatically community-wiki'd.

Comment: Any chance you have some funky user script on your browser? Try different and clean browser.

Comment: @Sha it's only that one question, I think. Does the edit history show up as "added 500" for you, or do you see the correct numbers?

Comment: Also, I just made a new edit on the answer, and the default description was correct this time.

Comment: Yes it shows "added 500" but maybe something in your browser pushed that while you edited. Unless this happens again or to someone else can't really see what we can do.

Comment: Hm....I'm running Chrome, and I do have [Lazarus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lazarus-form-recovery/loljledaigphbcpfhfmgopdkppkifgno?hl=en) running. Other than that I don't think I have any form-filling type plugins.

Comment: I'll keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your [first edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16331800/2) to that post added 500 characters to the body (I didn't count, but it looks reasonable). Then the next [two](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16331800/3) [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16331800/4) came shortly after that and each other. In such circumstances<sup>(1)</sup>, the edit summary field is pre-filled with the previous message, and you have to manually change it to get a different message.

The following edits were much later, so you got a new edit summary for those.

<sup>(1)</sup> I'm not entirely sure, but I think the criterion is that you start to edit within the grace period of the previous. If you finish the edit within the grace period (five minutes), no new revision is generated, otherwise, you get a new revision with the old message.

Comment: You, sir, are extremely clever. That is almost certainly what happened.